# What constitutes a "Near Miss"?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

In Jetpack Joyride, there are a few missions about having near misses with stuff. What, exactly, is considered a near-miss?

Comment: Exactly that -- if you get close to the hazard but do not get hit by it.

Comment: **HOW CLOSE?!**

Comment: It doesn't need to be that close, just a few 'feet' or so should do it.  It's dead easy to do it with the zappers.  Missiles are a little more tricky.

Comment: For missiles its easier to bait them to shoot just above ground level and then run under them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A "near miss" is when you go near enough to whatever the specified object was but not get hit. For zappers, for example, just fly extremely close to one end and it will count. If you have an active quest for this, you know you've done it correctly when you see an exclamation point pop up and hear a "correct" sound, for the lack of a better description.

Comment: There's also a visual cue, a sort of flash like a camera flash at the point of the miss.

Comment: I always saw an exclamation point pop up when I got one.

Comment: @Fluttershy Yup, I've completely forgotten about the exclamation point. Adding to my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Note that the exclamation point will only pop up if you have an active quest for Near Misses -- although I suppose that's the only time you really care anyway.

Comment: @Schism Thanks and edited my answer just for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go close to it, but don't get yourself killed. With horizontal zappers, if you stay close enough for long enough, it can count as 2 near misses.